# Does Session.partial_run execute all fetches, not only those requested?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Take this example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=())

foo = tf.Print(ph, [ph], 'foo')
bar = tf.Print(ph, [ph], 'bar')

sess = tf.Session()
h = sess.partial_run_setup([foo, bar], [ph])
# query "foo"
sess.partial_run(h, foo, feed_dict={ph: 0})
# prints:
#   bar[0]
#   foo[0]
```

Even though I am requesting only `foo`, it seems that both `foo` *and* `bar` operations are run.

Am I right, then, in assuming that `partial_run` always compute all `fetches` (and all other operations in the graph needed for their computation) specified in `partial_run_setup`, and not only those requested in `partial_run`, as for plain `run`?